# Assigning a WAR to a security domain in JBOSS

Tags: java, authentication, jboss, war

I am working on an assignment that has an ejb and war component. I have been told that the ejb has to be assigned to a security domain, which I have done by configuring the jboss-ejb3.xml file.

I also have to add the WAR to a security domain. How would I do that? Does that get configured in the web.xml file, or is there a jboss specific config file that I need to do that in? All of the setup on the server side has been setup, I just need to do the configuration within the application code(config files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a security domain in the `jboss-web.xml` file under `WEB-INF` folder. For example,

```
<security-domain>testSecurityDomain</security-domain>
```

Additionally you will need to specify an `AUTH` process in the `web.xml` file. By auth methods, I mean `BASIC`, `FORM`, or `DIGEST`. Example:

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

If you are looking for SSO between your EJB and Web app, then have them both point to the same security domain. Assuming the security domain is configured correctly and SSO valves are enabled, the rest should be taken care of by JBoss. Another thing to keep in the mind the security domain must match the JAAS domain name that you have set up in your security domain configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It is unbelievable that the security-domain has to be specified on EJBs when the WAR using that EJBs has already a binding to a security-domain.
This makes EJBs no more portable and reusable in different applications.
JBoss and Wildfly are killers of J2EE and reusable Java applications....

Better Payara and Glassfish !!!